# How to get MetroUI CSS Datepicker value with javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker, metro-ui-css

I'd like to be able to see the date selected with a Metro UI CSS datepicker using javascript. Eventually this data would be used for building a JSON object to be sent in an AJAX request. For now though, I'd be happy just to see it in a browser alert message.

Here's the datepicker control: http://metroui.org.ua/datepicker.html
Notice the second datepicker has a default value.

How can I use the browser console to get that default value into an alert message? Surely I'm missing something obvious, but I've had no luck doing things like checking "`val()`" of the input element, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a little workaround (quick and dirty): give a unique Id to the `<input type="text"...` into the `<div class="input-control text"...` and then let JQuery to make the magic!
Here is the code:

```
<div id="dpContainer" class="input-control text">
    <input id="inputToRead" type="text">
    <button class="btn-date"></button>
</div>

<script>
    function getDPValue(){
      var selectedDate = $('#inputToRead').val();
      return selectedDate;
    }
</script>
```

I know it's little bit dirty, probably you can get some useful hint from http://metroui.org.ua/calendar.html functions.

more quick and more dirty:

```
<script>
  function getDPValue(){
    return $('#dpContainer').children('input[type=text]').val();
  }
</script>
```

HTH,
Stefano.

Comment: This works great, and I hadn't noticed all of the examples on that Calendar page before either (not sure how I missed them #shrug...). Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

The *datepicker* has a *calendar* control inside of it. You can get the selected date of the *calendar* control running .calendar('getDate'). Then lets allow JQuery do his job and reach the *calendar* control inside the *datepicker*.

```
<div id="myDate" class="input-control text" data-role="datepicker" data-preset="2016-01-01">
    <input type="text">
    <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
</div>

<script>
    function getMyDate(){
        return $('#myDate .calendar').calendar('getDate');
    }
</script>

<button class="button" onclick="alert(getMyDate())">Show My Date</button>
```

Comment: You really should add some explanatory text to your answer.

Comment: While this code block _may_ answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.